# How to start over with SQLite (SQLAlchemy) database?

Tags: sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask web app using sqlalchemy and a sqlite database.

I deleted a column in my models.py and now everything is broken.

I can't db init, I can't db migrate, I can't do anything.

How can I completely delete all data in my database so I can start over?

Answer (score 0):

To delete a SQLite database:

```
$ rm path/to/database.extension
```